# jQuery click show/hide using 2 separate elements problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, show

I'm trying to get a form to show and hide using two different triggers. One element when clicked shows the div holding the form, then the cancel button of the form hides the div.

I've tried several options and cannot get this to work so I've stripped it down and put the code [here on jsfiddle (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/5CpeW/)

The containing div shows but then won't hide... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just `return false` from the cancel handler.

Otherwise the click event bubbles, and since the button is nested inside the `li` element that opens the form, both elements receive the click.

The *cancel* button tries to `hide` it and then the `li` re-opens it..

```
   $("#h-nav li#hn-contact #cancel").click(function() {
          $("#h-nav li#hn-contact").find("div.dd").hide();
           return false;
      });
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5CpeW/2/

---

Notice, since `id` are unique, you do not have to describe the hierarchy in your jquery selectors. Just use a selector from the last `id` and forward..

Answer (score 1):

This is due to event bubbling. Use return false in click event's callback.

```
$("#h-nav li#hn-contact #cancel").click(function() {
    $("#h-nav li#hn-contact").find("div.dd").hide();
    return false;
});
```

For more information on this subject, go to [Events Order](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) It's worth understanding when you're going to be dealing with javascript in the future.

That actually gives you the cross-browser way of stoping propagation:

```
if (!e) var e = window.event;
e.cancelBubble = true;
if (e.stopPropagation) e.stopPropagation();
```

Comment: Thanks for the link – always good to get a better understanding of things!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$("#h-nav li#hn-contact").click(function() {
    $(".dd").show();
});
```

But it would be better to give that div an id and use that.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest using toggle() rather than show/hide as then you don't need to change the manually behaviour when it is clicked

Comment: I was originally using toggle, but in the final version I'll be animating the opacity rather than showing and hiding. Toggle didn't allow me the visual effect I want to end up with.